# In what field do factors of polynomial belong?

Tags: field-theory

In my notes I found the following. Let $f\in F[X]$ and let $u$ be a root of $f$ then $f=(X-u)m$ where $m\in F(u)[X]$. What I don't understand is why $m\in F(u)[X]$?

Thanks

Comment: That's because $u$ doesn't necessarily lies in $F$, so when you perform the division by $x-u$, the quotient has coefficients in $F(u)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the Euclidean algorithm to divide $P$ by $Q=X-u$, you need for the coefficients of $Q$ and $P$ to lie in the same ground field. If they don't, you can still do it over an extension containing the coefficients, which is precisely what is done here.

Comment: Now I get it I basically have to view $f$ as a polynomial of $F(u)[X]$. Thanks

Comment: @TheGeometer You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it I think that $F(u)[X]$ means the ring of polynomials with coefficients from the field $F(u)$

For example say $x^2+1\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $u=i$ a root of $f$ , then $f=(x-i)(x+i)$ where $m=x+i\in \mathbb{R}(i)[X](=\mathbb{C}[X])$

Answer (score 1):

With the implicit assumptions added in bold:

> **Let $F$ be a field.** Let $f \in F[X]$ and let $u$ be a root of $f$ **in an extension $G$ of $F$** then $f = (X-u) m$ where $m \in F(u)[X]$.

Then it follows from factor theorem.

Comment: Would maybe be better to use $X$ instead of $x$ as the variable symbol as you specified it as such.